# Is there any issue except for Dina Dmalchusa in counterfeiting money?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, money, emes-truth-honesty, dina-dmalchusa-dina

If someone were to find a way to make exact forgery of currency (in such a way that it would be impossible for anyone to find that it's counterfeit), would there be any prohibition to do so (except Dina Dmalchusa)?

What if you live in a country without counterfeiting rules (say a country that wouldn't mind if someone forged the currency of its enemy) as then there would be no Dina Dmalchusa?

Answer (score 8):

Anytime that you purchase something using anything that you claim has value, but in fact is not what it appears, you are guilty of fraud and theft, both of which are Isurei DeOraitha (Biblical prohibitions). It has nothing to do with whether or not the country you are in considers it a felony or a misdemeanor, or even if it is encouraged as an economic weapon against its enemies.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, That doesn't sound very realistic. I strongly doubt that it's possible to create a counterfeit that's completely undetectable. At some point, someone will detect the counterfeit and refuse to honor it, and whoever was the last person to try to pass it will be out the nominal value. We don't know how many times it will change hands before this happens, but it is likely to happen.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, assuming it's never detected, adding money to the money supply that didn't exist before constitutes inflation, devaluing everyone else's money by a little bit. Whether that constitutes theft is perhaps an interesting question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses #1, My question is assuming one could do a perfect copy. Not very realistic, though possible. #2, you're right (that inflation maybe a form of stealing, though how much does counterfeiting influence inflation is another question), though that itself could be an answer.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill It is still fraud even if the recipient accepts it. Fraud works because the victim of the crime believes there is relative value in the transaction and participates willingly. Just because the victim would not know the difference does not negate the fact that a fraud was committed. If it were a different case, would you still ask the question? If you could commit the perfect crime, stealing a million-dollar diamond from a museum and replacing it with a replica that would never be detected, and then benefit from the real thing, would it be permissible 'Al Pi Halachah? No, no, no!

Comment: SethJ (@ShmuelBrill courtesy ping), I guess the question is whether a *perfectly* counterfeited dollar is, in fact, worth a dollar.

Comment: @IsaacMoses is a perfectly counterfeited diamond worth the same as a real one? Is a perfectly counterfeited Van Gogh worth the same as the real one? No, not because it will be found out. Because it's not the real thing. The value that is assigned to the original would not be transferred to the fake if it were revealed by Candid Camera (even if it were undetectable). The value that it is perceived to have is as fake as the item itself.

Comment: @SethJ the difference between those cases and the currency note is that the latter's value is entirely based on perception and consensus to begin with.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, the relative value of everything is entirely based on perception and consensus. The value of currency may be more subject to public perception in times of either economic success or crisis, but the reality is that those same factors have some impact (sometimes even more immediate) on other things of value - take gold in today's market, for example.

Comment: @SethJ Gold, diamonds, and art all have both intrinsic value and perceived value. To begin with, they're all nice to look at, and the first two have special physical properties. Currency has *only* perceived value.

Comment: I would think this would fall under the commandment to have honest weights and measures, which as the commentaries explain there, applies even if (or perhaps specifically because) no one can tell the difference

Comment: But @IsaacMoses, ultimately, the Van Gogh only has value because it was painted by Van Gogh. The diamond only has value because it is a diamond. Synthetic diamonds are available on the market, legally, and are in some cases of higher quality than natural diamonds. They are far less valuable, however, as are cultured pearls less valuable than standard pearls. The point is, fake is fake, even if nobody realizes it.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill: The piece of paper is not worth $20, he just thinks it is. Just like an illegal weight, which makes him think he has a pound, when he only has 9/10th of a pound.

Comment: ". Except instead of the Government printing it, you did." Which means it is not a piece of paper worth $20, but rather a piece of paper worth Jail time.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Even under a system of fiat currency, it is possible that it would be considered stealing the full face value from the government, rather than stealing less than a *shaveh p'ruta* from every individual currency holder. If so, there might be liability in *beis din*. Under a representative currency system, it would even more likely be considered theft from the government.

Answer (score 4):

Counterfeiting money is definitely *assur,* prohibited, by Halacha.

Why?  Just off the top of my head (I'm going to Wiki this, so feel free to add answers and sources):

- Vayikra 19:11 "לֹא, תִּגְנֹבוּ; וְלֹא-תְכַחֲשׁוּ וְלֹא-תְשַׁקְּרוּ, אִישׁ בַּעֲמִיתוֹ." "Don't steal, deal falsely, or lie."
- מִדְּבַר-שֶׁקֶר תִּרְחָק  (Prohibition against lying) [Shemot 23:7]
- Don't Steal ( Vayikra 19:11 and 19:13)
- Don't be a false witness (You're implicitly testifying that your money is legal and valid tender.)
- Don't desecrate God's name (which will surely happen if the forger is caught.)
- Violation of "Emulating God's Ways"
- Violation of Vayikra 25:14 ("Do business fairly.")
- Violation of "keep honest weights and measures."
- Violation of Genevah Daat ("stealing a person's thoughts")

Comment: IIRC the ten commandments' "don't steal" refers to kidnapping. And we don't generally decide _halacha_ by taking out our _chumashim_ and translating verses.

Comment: Not if he realizes after the fact that it's counterfeit. ... 
Yes, it does refer to kidnapping, which is why I included the other verses. ... Sure we do.  All Halacha is based on interpreting verses.  And in any event, the Rambam lists all of those in his List of Mitzvots, as well.

Comment: @ShmuelL, I didn't say _halacha_'s not decided by translating verses. I said _we_ don't decide _halacha_ by translating verses. So WADR it's insufficient to point to verses in _chumash_ to justify "Counterfeiting money is definitely _assur_".

Comment: @msh210, what if the question was, "Is it permitted to lie"?

Comment: @SethJ, same comment IMO.

Comment: @msh210 That's not true. If someone asks a basic question that can be answered by quoting a Pasuk, why is doing so wrong? In general, if a Mitzvah is straight from a Pasuk,I think quoting it is fair. Maybe lying is somewhat complicated, and it may require some exceptions included in a full answer, but it still is correct to answer with a direct citation of the Pasuk that states the Mitzvah.

Comment: @SethJ, I think it'd be more valuable to show also that _halacha_ treats that _pasuk_ as a source of _halacha_. Otherwise, people could quote the Decalogue as a source for not stealing, for example.

Comment: @msh210, true, but then comments on the answer would likely lead to a decent correction. Here, I think the answer works. If there is no obvious literature on counterfeit currency (which wouldn't surprise me), it would be enormously helpful as a guide to look at the Torah for related Mitzvoth. Although I just re-read the answer and see where you're coming from ("it's definitely prohibited by Halachah"). It's a bit awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Too much money in the economy leads to inflation, which leads to increased prices, which is in essence just stealing from everybody.

Comment: A source for the assertion that this counts halachically as theft would improve your answer.

Comment: @msh210, What do you mean halakhically?  Stealing is stealing.  Unless you are of the opinion that it is okay to steal from goyim, then there isn't anything to argue.

Comment: There are halachic parameters of what's considered stealing. Frankly, I doubt that this qualifies; in any event, a source for your assertion that it does would be valuable.

Comment: @msh210
Enlighten me; what are these halakhic parameters of which you speak?

Comment: @Adam Mining, say, gold also leads to inflation (as gold prices go down). How would printing money be different?

Comment: Adam, I don't know. I've never learned the _halachos_ of theft. I have no doubt that they exist, though. (Perhaps try _Choshen Mishpat_ chapters 348 through 377.) I'd think that, if you were posting an answer claiming that a particular action qualifies as theft, then you'd have a basis for saying so. Seemingly, though, you hadn't even known, until I mentioned it, that there *are* parameters of theft. -1.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill
The Fed controls the economy.  A gold standard is much stronger than using paper currency, since paper currency can be easily forged, but mining is the only way to bring money into the country.  And gold is something universally recognized as having value.

Comment: @Adam So why is it stealing?

Comment: @msh210
You claim that you don't know either.  I've never learned them either.  Seems like a good thing to learn.  I'm opening it up right now.  Interesting, geneivah and gezeilah.  I thought the two categories were geneivah and gezel...  Anyway, I can't believe I've never seen this before.  Thanks for showing me.  By the way, does anyone know the difference between a regular answer and a community wiki?

Comment: Adam, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740.