# Is one allowed to sell a forged painting?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, emes-truth-honesty

One makes an exact carbon-copy (perfect copy, in such a way that one will never be able to tell the difference between an original and a copy. For arguments sake, lets say through witchcraft) of (say) a work of art and destroys the original.

He then proceeds to sell this copy for the cost of an original work of art (say $1,000,000).

If he would have informed the buyer that this was just a copy, he would have only been able to make (for example) $5,000.

Does he have to (between him and Hashem, as nobody can prove it to be a forgery) pay back the difference? (He probably isn't allowed to misrepresent his work in the first place, but ex-post-facto is he allowed to keep the money)?

On one hand, inherently the painting isn't worth nearly as much as the selling-price, yet on the other hand it **is** worth that amount on the open market.

---

Based on comments from [Is there any issue except for Dina Dmalchusa in counterfeiting money?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12112/732)

Answer (score 3):

Isur of Genevat Daat is certainly present here (see Gemara Hullin 93b-94a, Rambam Hilchot Mechira 18, Shulhan Aruch Hoshen Mishpat 228). Whether this is Isur from the Torah or not is a totally different story. [Here](http://www.jewishvalues.us/uploads/104_Genevas_Daas.PDF) is a good list of Mare Mekemot whether it is Asur from the Torah or from Rabanan.

Comment: Can I upvote this answer more than once?!

Comment: I thought that was a given.